# Calculating the angle between two 3D vectors

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I am trying to calculate the angle between two 3D vectors in python and for some reason I am getting two different answers depending on how I plug it into my code and was wondering if someone could look over it and see my mistakes.

Lets just assume by vectors are numpy arrays [1, 2, 3] and [2 ,3, 4] for the purpose of this example

Currently my code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import math

def CalculateAngleBetweenVector(vector, vector2):

    dp = np.dot(vector, vector2)

    maga = math.sqrt((vector[0] ** 2) + vector[1] ** 2 + vector[2] ** 2)
    magb = math.sqrt((vector2[0] ** 2) + vector2[1] ** 2 + vector2[2] ** 2)
    magc = maga * magb

    dpmag = dp / magc

    angleindeg = ((math.acos(dpmag)) * 180) / math.pi

    return angleindeg

#Assume these vectrs have come from elsewhere and are not unit vectors so I first calculate the unit vectors

vectorA = vectorA / (vectorA ** 2).sum() ** 0.5
vectorB = vectorB / (vectorB ** 2).sum() ** 0.5

#I want to plot these on a quiver graph so the next few lines are for that

VectorDif = np.subtract(vectorA, vectorB)
Vector = np.add((0, 0, 1), VectorDif)
Vector = Vector / (Vector ** 2).sum() ** 0.5
```

Ok so now the confusion comes. There should be two ways for me to calculate the angles and they should produce the same result but they dont.

The first way is:

```
CalculateAngleBetweenVector((0,0,1), Vector)
```

and the second way is:

```
CalculateAngleBetweenVector(vectorA, vectorB)
```

As far as I can see these should produce the same result but they don't and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why would you expect the angle between `(a - b + i )` and `i` (your second calculation)  to be the same as the angle between `a` and `b`? There is just no reason at all.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I don’t think that is what I wrote

Comment: It is, actually. `Vector` is basically `a - b` plus `(0, 0, 1)`, and your last calculation is the angle between this vector and `(0, 0, 1). It can't be the same as the angle between `a` and `b`.

Comment: I thought I was calculating the difference between the vectors and then adding it to the z axis. Surely that angle should be the same as the angle between a and b?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think my vector maths is lacking. Would you mind briefly explaining why adding the difference between two vectors to a vector will mean the angle at which the new vector sits relative to the vector it was added to would not be equal to the angle between the two original vectors?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the maths rather than the code.
Try `vectorA = [1, 0, 0]` and `vectorB = [0, 1, 0]` -> angle of 90°.

I get `vector = [1, -1, 1] / sqrt(3)` -> angle of `acos(1 / sqrt(3))`.

Comment: Dammit. I haven’t done vector maths since a level so I may have made a stupid mistake somewhere, thanks for providing a good way to test.

Comment: If I plug  0,0,1 and 0,1,0 I get 90 degrees for everything.

Comment: I get 54° for the first, 90° for the second. If you're on python 2.7 it might make a difference if you use `[1.0, 0.0, 0.0]` vs `[1, 0, 0]`.